# How to get IP Address on Azure Web App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to assign an IP to a Azure App Service? I just deployed my application and it's working correctly. But the problem is we need our domain to point to that App Service. Since our domain is website.com and the app service domain is website.azurewebsites.net is there a way to point the website.com to the azure url? We have a reverse proxy where we can just assign the IP and that will load the site. So if the site is website.azurewebsites.net and ip is 123 then in our reverse proxy we just assign 123 to our domain website.com. So whenever someone access website.com they are presented with website.azurewebsites.net. Is there a way to assign an IP to this app service?

Comment: see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain

Comment: thanks @silent for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Services is a shared servers which means many App Services is behind same IP hence you need to configure Custom Domain on your App Service to get it to work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

The shared IP can be found under your App Service on the blade Settings->Properties.

The name is "Virtual IP address"

Comment: When it says custom DNS name does it mean that it will affect our existing DNS? Because we don't want to configure any DNS name for our current site.. We just want our DNS to point to that app service

Comment: You will need to verify you are the owner of the domain name by either using CNAME or A-Record since the IP is shared otherwise the App Service wont listen to calls to that DNS record.

Comment: @MadzQuestioning One Clarification, there is no way to access the App Service using IP Address, you need to access it by a DNS name. So either you use the azuresites.net DNS name or you use a custom domain which you own by your self.

Comment: thanks a lot that could be a solution.. will look into this and accept your answer as solution if this is good

Answer (score 1):

Like silent mentioned, use CNAME mapping to map the domain, alternatively Web Apps actually have a list of possible outbound IP addresses, but I dont think thats reasonable, just use CNAME (you also need to verify your domain in Azure).